# Why it has the type Nothing?

Tags: java, scala, testcontainers

I am trying to use https://www.testcontainers.org/ in my bdd test as follows:

```
final class DetectorSpec extends BddSpec {

  private val listener1 = TestProbe()
  private val listener2 = TestProbe()

  private val detector = system.actorOf(DetectorSupervisor.props)

  var sapMock = new FixedHostPortGenericContainer("zerocoder/sapmock:2.1.1")
    .withFixedExposedPort(8080, 9090)


  override def afterAll(): Unit = {
    TestKit.shutdownActorSystem(system)
  }
  ......
```

The problem on the code above is, the variable `sapMock` has type `Nothing`. It seems, that method chaining does not work.

Why the variable `sapMock` has type `Nothing`?

[image]

Comment: What are all those `listenerN`, `detector`, `afterAll` and `DetectorSpec` itself good for? They don't seem to be used in the definition of `sapMock` in any way. It's not minimal.

Comment: I am trying to test my actors, that because I need them all.

Comment: I did not paste all codes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`FixedHostPortGenericContainer`](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/testcontainers/containers/FixedHostPortGenericContainer.java) requires an F-bounded parameter type of the container itself. You didn't specify any type arguments at all, so it seems that you ended up with something like a raw type.

Try

```
class SapMock extends 
FixedHostPortGenericContainer[SapMock]("zerocoder/sapmock:2.1.1")


val sapMock = new SapMock.withFixedExposedPort(8080, 9090)
```

Comment: what is `F-bounded parameter type` ?

Comment: @zero_coding `<SELF extends FixedHostPortGenericContainer<SELF>>`. Generally, any type parameter with constraint that looks like `X <: F[X]`.

Comment: The `F-bounded` makes me confuse.